# How could I create a recurring payment for different products in Stripe every X quantity of months?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, stripe-payments, recurring-billing

I have a web app in Ruby on Rails where I'd like to manage recurring payment every X quantity of months with different prices for every product, is it possible?
Btw I'm doing it using Ruby on Rails and Stripe

Comment: Subscription Schedules is probably what you're after: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules

Comment: @PaulAsjes thank you man, it's the answer. I only have a doubt, so do I need to create: Product -> Plan -> Subscription Schedule, right?

Comment: Answering myself...
I had to create Customer, Product, Price and finally SubscriptionSchedule